# Does buttons and links increase mobile responsivness?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am curious about this one. Does creating a div imitating a button (with 'click' event binded to it) is user-friendly? I mean, does all mobile browsers accurately treat it and always fire event when div is clicked?
Does replacing such constructions with normal buttons increases responsivness on mobile devices?

Comment: @Tabot you asked very vague. For behavior most mobile browsers now responds correctly given your function is correct. For appearance a good reset will make both div and buttons look unique across all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google describes this pretty well i think [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons).

So as described there, handling the click event adds a 300ms delay because it is waiting to see if it is a double-tap.

> The technique involves a bit of JavaScript that allows the button to
>   respond to `touchend` events rather than `click` events. `Touchend` events
>   are fired with no delay so this is significantly faster than `click`
>   events, however there are a few problems to consider:
>
> - If the user tapped somewhere else on the screen and then invokes a
>     `touchend` on the button then we should not fire a `click`.
> - If the user touches down on the button and then drags the screen a bit and then
>     invokes a `touchend` on the button then we should not fire a `click`.
> - We want to highlight the button when the user touches down to give it a
>     pressed state.
>
> We can solve the first two problems by monitoring `touchstart` and `touchmove` events as well.
>   We should only consider a `touchend` on the button if there was previously a `touchstart` on the button. Also if there exists a `touchmove` anywhere that goes past a
>   certain threshold from the `touchstart` then we should not handle the
>   `touchend` as a `click`.
>
> We can solve the third problem by adding an `onclick` handler to the
>   button as well. Doing so will allow the browser to properly treat it
>   as a button, and our `touchend` handler will ensure that the button is
>   still fast. Also, the presence of an `onclick` handler serves as a good
>   fallback for browsers that don’t support touch events.

Another advice from experience would be to avoid anchors for buttons.

They recommend using Touchend instead of click.